# How many GB is the ethereum Blockchain goerli and other testnets?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, nodes, goerli

How many GB is the ethereum Blockchain goerli and others testnets?

I could not find this information for testnets, if anyone knows this info using diferents sync modes in Geth (snap, full and archive) i apreciate.

Comment: I run a full node and a validator in the Goerli network, it is not over 100gb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 21 Dec 2022:

- Goerli full ≈176G
- Sepolia full ≈5.5G

Comment: how did you find this information?

Comment: @JanacMeena we run thousands of various blockchain nodes at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com)

Comment: @EugeneAseev may I know where can I find live updated data?

Comment: @CHOOYJ we've just built a website for that: https://chainstats.org/